# jqGrid - event on grid initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jqgrid

I'm using jquery jqGrid plugin and I need to fire event on grid initialization. I tested `gridComplete` and `loadComplete` events, but these events raised after every server request. I need an event that raise **just once and after initialization of the grid**. I read [jqGrid events list](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events), but I don't see any related event to my requirement. Is there any way? Thanks for your attention.

**Update:**

Thanks to @Oleg for his answer. I'm using jqGrid 4.6 and used @Oleg's suggested events with this pattern:

```
  $('#grid1').jqGrid('setGridParam', {
                onSelectRow: function(id) {
                    //This event raised without problem.
                },
                onInitGrid: function(){
                  //This event does not raised.
                },
                jqGridInitGrid: function(){
                  //This event does not raised.
                },
            });
```

But this is not working. What is the correct way to use these two events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly the jQuery event `jqGridInitGrid` or `onInitGrid` callback is what you need. It's the first events/callbacks which will be called once during creating the grid after the outer part of jqGrid will be constructed and before the first filling of jqGrid with data. The event/callback can be used in jqGrid 4.6/4.7

The new version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/), which I'm developing now, contains additionally `beforeInitGrid` callback and `jqGridBeforeInitGrid` event. The callback/event will be called **before** jqGrid start processing of input parameters. So it's possible for example make any *modification* of the parameter. You can for example modify/generate `colModel` based on the input data.

So the best choice of the callbacks/events depend on at what moment of initialization you need to do some changes and from which version of jqGrid you use.

Comment: I updated my question and add your suggested events, please read my question again. Thank you so much.

Comment: @hamed: Sorry, but I don't see any changes of your question. Which version of jqGrid you use? Do you tried `onInitGrid` or other? Is it not what you need? What should **be already initialized** in the grid at the moment of the call of your callback/event? What you need to do in the callback/event?

Comment: I need to disable the grid after initialization. But just once and not always after every server request.

Comment: @hamed: I see now your changes. The callback `onInitGrid` should do work in jqGrid 4.6 (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L2932-L2933)). To use `jqGridInitGrid` you need register the event **before creating** the grid like below: `$("#grid").bind("jqGridInitGrid", function() {alert("in jqGridInitGrid");})`. You can't use `setGridParam` **after** the grid is created because it's too late.

Comment: Ok, You are right. I found the problem from your explanation. Thank you for your attention again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71937/discussion-between-hamed-and-oleg).