# Moving summary footer to grouping header

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there other way to have summary at grouping header other than using `groupSummaryPos:['header']` ? I am using jqGrid v4.6.0 and unfortunately I cannot upgrade to higher version.

I have a table that I implemented using jqGrid in my project. The gridOptions are very similar with the one mentioned in my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378580/put-specific-data-in-jqgrid-summary-view-header/29379822?noredirect=1#comment46941295_29379822)
As you can see from the plunkr, the demo works fine and I can show summary on header. However, when I moved the code to my project, the summary always shows on footer. The only difference between my project and the plunkr code is in my project, I am using a reusable component that will initialize jqGrid. I have debugged the code to see if the `groupSummaryPos = ['header']` being overridden somewhere in my project by that reusable component, but it gives me no luck.

So, I have decided to go for a workaround. I tried to a 'hack-move' by moving the summary footer DOM element to the grouping header, after the GRID_COMPLETE event, using

```
var footerContent = jQuery('.jqfooter').children;
jQuery('.jqgroup')[0].children[0].removeAttribute('colspan');
jQuery('.jqgroup')[0].appendChild(footerContent[0]); // till all columns
```

However, this doesn't work because the appendChild will move each column in random order (I'm not sure why).. In summary, I have tried to use the proper way, which is specifying `groupSummaryPos: ['header']` in my colOptions, and also a 'really bad' hack way, but it's not working too.

Is there a possible way to move summary footer to group header without using groupSummaryPos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should locale which part of your code change `groupSummaryPos` option. The 'hack-move' solution seems me the wrong way.

You can try to reset `groupSummaryPos` to `'header'` inside of `onInitGrid` callback as the first attempt. You should verify additionally that `gridview: true` is set too and nobody modify it.

The `groupSummaryPos` option will be used inside of `groupingRender` method whith will be called inside of `addJSONData`. So you can use `beforeProcessing` callback (if you loads the data from the server) or `beforeRequest`. So, if the resetting of `groupSummaryPos` to `'header'` inside of `onInitGrid` will not work you can do this inside of `beforeRequest` or inside of `beforeProcessing`.

Comment: hi Oleg, thanks again for your reply! First I checked my `groupSummaryPos` value inside the onInitGrid and the value is correct, it's still `header`. I also added `gridview: true` and ensure nobody modify it. the way I used onInitGrid is as described by your old answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778434/jqgrid-event-on-grid-initialization . However the summary is still shown in the footer. My data is from local tho (static variable). Is there any other ways to do it? Thanks again beforehand!

Comment: I found the reason why. In my project, I downloaded the dependency using Bower for jqGrid 4.6.0 and use the minified version. Weirdly, the minified version included in jqGrid 4.6.0 is version 4.5.2 (is this a defect?). That's why the summaryPos doesn't work since I believe groupSummaryPos header is not supported in 4.5.2.. Thanks Oleg for ur answer!!

Comment: and I believe you pointed this out to Tony Tomov too https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/7216e3866b9c49ebee93d6e09dc5a72eb0460d89

Comment: @blenzcoffee: You are welcome! Now everything is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why. In my project, I downloaded the dependency using Bower for jqGrid 4.6.0 and use the minified version. Weirdly, the minified version included in jqGrid 4.6.0 is version 4.5.2 (is this a defect?).This is mentioned in the comments section here

https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/7216e3866b9c49ebee93d6e09dc5a72eb0460d89

That's why the summaryPos doesn't work since I believe groupSummaryPos header is not supported in 4.5.2.. 
The plunkr version works because it's using the right minified version. Thanks Oleg for ur answer!!